# Select elements with attribute value matching attribute value of different element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

With CSS selectors, is it possible to select elements with an attribute value that is the same as the attribute value of another specified element?  For example:

```
<a class="important" href="foo.bar"></a>
```

will always appear on the page, but the `href` might be anything.  Then further on the page may be something like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="bar.foo"></a>
    <a href="foo.bar"></a>
    <a href="bar.bar"></a>
    <a href="foo.bar"></a>
</li>
```

This list again may contain anything but could contain `<a>` elements with the same `href="foo.bar"`.

I want to be able to select those `<a>` elements within the list that have an `href` attribute **that matches the `href` attribute of any `<a class="important">`**

Is this possible with CSS alone?  I know this could of course be done in javascript by making sure those specific `<a>` elements within the list are created with a class attribute, but I'm interested in if there is a purely CSS solution.

Comment: Not only can you use a selector that matches `[attr="value"]`, you can do a partial on a value which may increase the range of matched elements. ex. `[title^="Java"]` The `^=` means the value begins with... So that selector would mean find elements with the `title` attribute that has any value that begins with "Java" so  `<div title="Java">` and `<span title="JavaScript">` would both match.

Answer (score 1):

yes,

syntax

```
[{attri}={value}]
```

like this

```
.important{
   color:#0f0;
}

.important[href="bar.foo"]{
   color:#00f;
}

.important[href="bar.bar"]{
   color:#f00;
}
```

[Mozilla Documentation - Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: This matches the .important element itself, not the other elements. Of course, you could write something like .important[href="bar.foo"] ~ ul a[href="bar.foo"], etc assuming the ul is a following sibling of .important, but that misses the point of the question I would think.